Asymptotes of an integral
Given the function
$$f(x,y)=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{u}} e^ {-\frac{(y-u)^2}{2}} \, du$$
for $x>0$, I am wondering if it is possible to find an explicit expression for it, even an appromimate one, for $y \rightarrow - \infty$ and $y \rightarrow \infty$. I noticed that $f(x,y)$ behaves as a kind of exponential decay for $y \rightarrow - \infty$, while it is a Gaussian for $y \rightarrow \infty$, see please the following plot.
f[x_, y_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  1/Sqrt[u] Exp[-((y - u)^2/2)] Exp[-(x^2/u)], {u, 0, Infinity}]
ListPlot[{Table[{x, f[x, -1.5]}, {x, 0, 5, 0.05}], 
  Table[{x, f[x, 7]}, {x, 0, 5, 0.05}]}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]


I also noticed that the integrand function has a peculiar shape reaching a maximum very close to $u=0$ for $y \rightarrow -\infty$, while for large $y$ it is a Gaussian again, see below.
integrand[x_, y_, u_] := 1/Sqrt[u] Exp[-((y - u)^2/2)] Exp[-(x^2/u)]
Plot[integrand[0.2, -2, u], {u, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"u", "integrand"}]


Plot[integrand[0.2, 6, u], {u, 0, 11}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"u", "integrand"}]


Thanks for any help.
UPDATE
I am not sure but probably $y$ can be brought outside the integral. The integral can be re-written:
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{u}} e^ {-\frac{y^2}{2}} e^{yu} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\, du$$
which is
$$e^ {-\frac{y^2}{2}} \int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{u}} e^{yu} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\, du$$
and, using the power series expansion for the exponential,
$$e^{yu}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(yu)^k}{k!}$$
we have
$$e^ {-\frac{y^2}{2}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{y^k}{k!} \int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{u}} u^k e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\, du$$

Some thoughts.
Case $y\to \infty$.
Assume that $x$ is fixed.
Let $y > 1$. We have $f(x, y) = I_1 + I_2 + I_3$ where
$$I_1 := \int_{y-\sqrt{y}}^{y + \sqrt{y}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{u}} \mathrm{e}^ {-\frac{(y-u)^2}{2}} \, \mathrm{d}u
= \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{y-v}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac12 v^2}}{\sqrt{y-v}}\,\mathrm{d} v,$$
and
$$I_2 := \int_0^{y-\sqrt{y}}, \quad I_3 := \int_{y+\sqrt{y}}^\infty.$$
First, we have
$$I_1 \le \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{y+\sqrt{y}}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac12 v^2}}{\sqrt{y-\sqrt{y}}}\,\mathrm{d} v 
= \frac{\mathrm{erf}(2^{-1}\sqrt{2y})\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{y-\sqrt{y}}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{y + \sqrt{y}}}
=: J_1.$$
Second, we have
$$I_1 \ge \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{y-\sqrt{y}}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac12 v^2}}{\sqrt{y+\sqrt{y}}}\,\mathrm{d} v
= \frac{\mathrm{erf}(2^{-1}\sqrt{2y})\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{y+\sqrt{y}}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{y - \sqrt{y}}}
=: J_2.$$
Third, we have
$$
 I_2 \le  \int_0^{y-\sqrt{y}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}  \mathrm{e}^ {-\frac{y}{2}} \, \mathrm{d}u = 2\sqrt{y - \sqrt{y}}\,\mathrm{e}^{-y/2} =: J_3. 
$$
Fourth, we have
$$I_3 \le \int_{y+\sqrt{y}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \mathrm{e}^ {-\frac{(y-u)^2}{2}} \, \mathrm{d}u
= \frac{(1 - \mathrm{erf}(2^{-1}\sqrt{2y}) )\sqrt{2\pi}}{2\sqrt{y}} \sim \frac{1}{y}\mathrm{e}^{-y/2} =: J_4.$$
From above, we have
$$J_2 \le I \le J_1 + J_3 + J_4.$$
Then, we can prove that
$$\lim_{y\to \infty} \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{y}}\mathrm{e}^{- \frac{x^2}{y}}}{I} = 1.$$

Awesome! Thank you, River Li. It seems that $I_2$ goes to $0$ as $y \rightarrow \infty$ and quicker than $I_1$, so we can discard its asymptote and the result is given by $I_1$ alone.

@umby I am not sure. A rigorous proof is needed. E.G. can we prove that $I \sim  \frac{\mathrm{erf}(2\sqrt{2})\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{y}}\mathrm{e}^{- \frac{x^2}{y}}$?

Dear River Li, thank you.  $I_1$ is the one you wrote as $y \rightarrow \infty$, I think. If this is true, $I_2$ contains $y$ at the numerator of the eponential while $I_1$ has $y$ at the denominator of the exponential, then $I_2$ goes faster to $0$ as $y$ grows. Not a rigorous proof however.

with no prove: $$\frac{e^{-\frac{2 x^2+y^3}{2 y}} \sqrt{\pi } \left(\sqrt{2} e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}-i e^{\frac{x^2}{y}} \cos \left(2 x \sqrt{y}\right)-e^{\frac{x^2}{y}} \sin \left(2 x
\sqrt{y}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{y}}$$ if $x>0$ and $y\to \infty$

@umby I edited my answer to obtain $I \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{y}}\mathrm{e}^{- \frac{x^2}{y}}$.

@RiverLi, great! Thank you. Any thought about $y \rightarrow -\infty$?

@umby Perhaps the approach here is complicated for $y\to - \infty$. You may try the saddle point method: see e.g. https://www.physics.ucla.edu/~kevinchen/physics/saddle.pdf, or, https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2021f/saddle.pdf

Let's first get rid of the square root in the integrand:
$$I=f(x,y)=\int_0^{\infty } 2e^{-\frac{x^2}{u^2}} e^ {-\frac{(y-u^2)^2}{2}} \, du$$
Here we can use the fact that the integrand
$$F(u)=2e^{-\frac{x^2}{u^2}} e^ {-\frac{(y-u^2)^2}{2}} \, du$$
has a sharp maximum as a function of $u$.
In this case, we can use a ready-made formula, so to speak, "off the shelf":
$$I\approx \sqrt{-\frac{2\pi F^3(u_{m})}{ \frac{d^2 F(u_{m}) }{d u^2}}}$$
where $u_{m}$ is the maximum value of the integrand.
The minus sign under the square root is because at the maximum point
$$\frac{d^2 F(u_{m}) }{d u^2}<0$$
The derivation of this approximate formula is too long to present here.
I believe it is covered in many relevant guides.
Next, we calculate the maximum point $u_{m}$  of the integrand.
By equating the derivative of the integrand to zero, we arrive at a cubic equation:
$$u^6-yu^4-x^2=0$$
The solutions of this equation can be presented in closed form in elementary functions.
I just took some random parameters $x=2,y=3$
The cubic equation gives the maximum point at $u_{m}=1.83175$
The exact value of the integral is $I=0.353935$
The approximate formula gives $I\approx 0.354289$
The absolute deviation from the exact value is $0.000354$
Supplement
I will try to briefly describe how to get this approximate expression
Consider an integral with a sharp maximum at $x _{m}$
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty }f(x)dx$$
I will use the following notation for brevity
$$f''(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d^2}f(x) }{\mathrm{d} x^2}$$
Now the problem is how to choose the integration range $\Delta x$
The main idea is that $\Delta x$
is determined by the value of $f''(x_{m})$
We develop the $f(x)$ Taylor series around the maximum and keep only two terms:
$$f(x)=f(x_{m})+\frac{(x-x_{m})^2f''(x_{m})}{2}$$
We will find $\Delta x = x-x_{m}$ such that $f(x)=0$:
$$\Delta x =C_{1}\sqrt{-\frac{ f(x_{m})}{f''(x_{m})} }$$
where the constant $C_{1}$ has yet to be determined
So we get an estimate for the integral
$$I\approx f(x_{m})\Delta x=C_{1}\sqrt{-\frac{ f^3(x_{m})}{f''(x_{m})} }$$
To determine $C_{1}$ , we require that this estimate be exact for the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty }C_{2}\exp{-ax^2} dx=C_{2}\sqrt{\frac{ \pi}{a} }$$
So here $f(x)=C_{2}\exp{-ax^2}$ and $x_{m}=0$
The result is an equation for determining $C_{1}$:
$$\frac{C_{1}C_{2}}{\sqrt{2a}}=C_{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$
or
$$C_{1}=\sqrt{2\pi}$$
Thus, the obtained result is designed for an exponential integrand.
Similarly, we can derive our formula for an integrand of a different character if the integrand has a sharp maximum.

Dear Martin Gales, I am shamefull to say, but I am lost on getting rid of the square root in the integrand. Could you please help me a bit on this point? Thanks.

@umby   Change of variable: u=z^2

Dear Martin Gales, many thanks, @MartinGales. Can you please give a reference for the very interesting "off the shelf" formula?

This is avery nice approximation. By the way $$u_m=\sqrt{\frac{y \left(2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{27 x^2}{2 y^3}+1\right)\right)+1\right)}{3}}$$

You inspired me ! I hope that you do not mind I started from your answer. If you do, let me know and I shall delete. Cheers :-)

@ClaudeLeibovici Your posts are also inspiring to me, so let's go.

@MartinGales, everything clear up to the introduction of $f(x)=C_{2}\exp({-ax^2})$ and $x_m=0$. Should we reduce our integrand to this form?

@umby Not really. This is simply to set the numerical value of the constant

@MartinGales, thank you for the amazing formula!

@umby Glad to hear you like it (-:

Applying the mothod proposed by @MartinGales, I found the asymptote for $y→-∞$, but the value of $u_m$ if different for the one found by Claude Leibovivi or Mariusz Iwaniuk: $u_m=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[4]{-y}}$. The result should be $\sqrt{-\frac{\pi }{y}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-y} \left((-y)^{3/2}+4 x\right)}$ (for $y<0$). It seems to work, I am not completely sure however.

@MartinGales, but to have $C_{1}=\sqrt{2\pi}$ our function has to be $f(x)=C_{2}\exp({-ax^2})$, isn't it? CAn we reduce our original function to this form?

@umby I am not sure that this approximation works for very large parameter values

Using @Martin Gales's nice solution, we have
$$u_m=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3} y \left(1+2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(1+\frac{27 x^2}{2 y^3}\right)\right)\right)}$$
Computing
$$I\sim\sqrt{-\frac{2\pi F^3(u_{m})}{ \frac{d^2 F(u_{m}) }{d u^2}}}$$ and expanding for large values of $y$
$$I\sim \sqrt{\frac {2\pi} y}\,\,\Bigg(1-\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{x^4}{2 y^2}-\frac{x^2 \left(x^4+9\right)}{6 y^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{y^4}\right)  \Bigg)$$

Thank you @ClaudeLeibovici. This is exsactly the solution proposed by River Li. Thank you. I am trying to apply this approach to the $y \rightarrow -\infty$ limit.

@umby. Not exactly. I differ at the last term. But this was done using  Martin Gales approximation. So River Li must be correct.

@umby. If we use  Mariusz Iwaniuk result, we have exactly River Li's result

But $u_m$ you found is valid for large and large negative $y$? in this case it can be used for $y \rightarrow -\infty$. Thanks, @ClaudeLeibovici.

@umby. No ! The discriminant of the cubic in $u^2$ is $\Delta=-x^2 \left(27 x^2+4 y^3\right)$. So, it can be positive if $y<0$ and, in this case, the solution will be trigonometric. I shall look at this tomorrow morning.

There should be an error, then, @ClauseLeibovivi, since the result of River Li, that works fine, is never negative increasing $x$, while your becomes wildly negative with the increase of $x$.
